# replacing Enter key code with TAB key code in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a script in javascript that replace <kbd>Enter</kbd> with <kbd>TAB</kbd> key:

```
function ReplaceEnterWithTab() { if (event.keyCode == 13) event.keyCode = 9; return false; }
```

and I use it this way:

```
txt.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", "ReplaceEnterWithTab();");
```

this code work nice.Now I want to develop a script with jQuery that will not need to add `OnKeyDown` attribute.please consider this sample page:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" CssClass="EntTab"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" CssClass="EntTab"></asp:TextBox>
    <br />
    <br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" CssClass="EntTab">
        <asp:ListItem>1</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>2</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" />
</div>
</form>
```

I write this code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('.EntTab').on('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) e.keyCode = 9;
        });

    });
```

the problem is when I press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on `TextBox1`, `Button1` cause page post back. How I can solve this issue?

thanks

Comment: why not just call `ReplaceEnterWithTab` with `keydown` on your body tag? that way, all the elements will work.

Comment: Linked: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5726923/55209

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".EntTab").bind("keypress", function(e) {

        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            var inps = $("input, select"); //add select too
            for (var x = 0; x < inps.length; x++) {
                if (inps[x] == this) {
                    while ((inps[x]).name == (inps[x + 1]).name) {
                    x++;
                    }
                    if ((x + 1) < inps.length) $(inps[x + 1]).focus();
                }
            }   e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Did you mean something like that.

Comment: try adding e.preventDefault()

Comment: @sundhir : I don't want add `\t` in my text inputs.I want set focus to next control

Comment: thanks it works for `input`s and I change it to `.EntTab`.it has a problem that when `DropDownList1` got focus and I press `Enter` key I got an error message

Comment: see edited code, added select also, should work for dropdown as well

Comment: Sorry but another problem your code cause I can't enter any text in text boxes

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to cancel the event propagation, add `return false` to the keydown callback:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.EntTab').on('keydown', function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) e.keyCode = 9;
        return false;
    });
});
```

Also, Button tag in ASP.NET has `UseSubmitBehavior` [flag set to true](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior.aspx) by default, which causes the button to be rendered as `input type="submit"` tag. Try setting it to false, to get the behavior like described in the following answer: [Use Javascript to change which submit is activated on enter key press](https://stackoverflow.com/a/382179/55209)

Comment: Did you try to add the `e.preventDefault()` just before the if statement?