# Do all browser's treat enter (key 13) the same inside form?

Tags: html, forms, webforms, submit, form-submit

I have a form with multiple submit buttons, each of which is relevant to how the user wants the data saved and/or loaded.

The problem is (or was) that if a user pressed enter on the last (or any other) input within the form, the submit button that seemed to be called was the "load saved formed" which is at the top of the form. All attempts to user javascript to have the return button default to the "save form" seemed useless, almost as if the browser was too busy already submitting the form to have any js interfere.

Finally, in FireFox 3.5, I actually had the server-side script echo out what it received for the `post` variable and discovered that none of the submit button values were being passed back to the server. As it turns out, I have hooks in the script for when the user hits "Save" or "Save and Print", etc, but if the user uses the "load page" it simply updates a variable and continues loading the page normally with that variable in context.

So with no submit button value at all, it did the same thing, it simply loaded the page.

So, on to the big question:

Is this typical browser behavior? Maybe even reliable browser behavior? Will hitting enter always submit the form as though no submit button was pressed at all, or do some browsers like to pick a button to use as the default when the user presses enter?

If it is typical behavior, what is the suggested course of action? I was going to have the script save anything no matter what, so long as there was data in the form, but then I realized that this was even more dangerous, because if the user loads one saved form, changes there mind, and changes the form dates and hits "Load Form", then it will save the form data from the pervious form for the new dates they have requested.

I considered setting it up so that *changing* the load form inputs (selects with dates and other particulars) would clear the form so that the server still recieved an empty form and thus would not overwrite any previous data, but this is risky as well, as many users will certainly notice and think that their data has been lost, etc, and there is always the slight chance that the user will be almost done with the form, go up to the top and fiddle with the form-load selects just to confirm they chose the right what nots and then be forced to start from scratch.

I should just have two forms, one for loading, one for the data, but the problem with that is that all of the data in the load part of the form does get used by the main form. I could write more js to combine the two on submit, or hide the data in the second form, but all of that seems clunky.

Essentially, I need a setup such that the top part of the form is independent of the main form, but not vice versa. Submitting the upper form does not submit the lower, but submitting the lower does submit the higher.

Okay,I've gone on long enough. Basically I'm wondering if a solution already exists or if anyone else has run into this and found a clever fix. I thought simply having the form save whenever the form wasn't empty was pretty clever, until it occurred to me that when the user goes to the page, it auto-loads the most applicable form given the date, and thus changing the load variables will almost always caused trouble.

---

Having read the possible duplicate that Artelius was good enough to draw my attention to, I'm still unclear on the consistency across browsers regarding the Enter button as submit.

It seems that almost everyone in that question assumed that hitting enter presses the first available submit, which was also my assumption until a friend suggested I hide (via CSS) another submit button at the top of the form with whatever I wanted enter to achieve. It was when this got me the same results that I finally viewed what was being passed to the server (ie nothing in terms of a submit value).  So that means either

a) the "enter as no submit button just submit" is new behavior for some or all browsers,

b) the "enter as just submit" vs "enter as first submit button" is just browser choice, no trends, just typical cross-browser unreliability, or

c) Everyone just keeps assuming that the "enter as first submit button" is the case because most of us only code `if (situation1) else (assume not situation1)` and none of us are really sure what the browser is doing.

I highly doubt it's that last one, but then again, I also highly doubt most of us know which browsers do which. I'd sure like it if there was a straight answer I could pass along.

Oh, and finally: While I know it would be far simpler to use buttons, and I am taking that under serious consideration, I would also like to consider other options, since really the only need for less submit buttons I have is for when users hit enter instead of one of the buttons.

Actually, let me get carried away one more second:

The only thing I really need to know is whether or not they hit enter FROM one of the text inputs. If I could pass that along to the server, I'd know if I should save or reload the form.  But the problem is (or at least what I've had troubles with) is that when the user hits enter in an input, it seems like there isn't any more playtime with js to capture anything, and in some cases, it seems like the browser is triggering the `onclick` for whichever submit button and thus not really allowing me to know the real event that triggered that. I'll play around more with jquery, but has this behavior been observeed by anyone else?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48/multiple-submit-buttons-on-a-form

Comment: Doh! Good catch. I'd still like to get some more feedback on if there is a way to do 2 forms but have one trigger the other (so to speak).

Answer (score 1):

My best advise would be to only have on submit button, and let that submit what ever is the most common usage of the form. Let the rest of the buttons just be normal buttons, which you can hook click events onto.

Just make sure you make it very clear which button will be "pressed" when the user hits enter. Let the submit button be the biggest one. If you have 3 buttons that are used equally as much, I would just drop having a submit button at all...

**edit:** I'm pretty sure most browsers will post all the data inside a form. If you want to do some checking on the data before posting you could add a listener for onsubmit

```
<form onsubmit="checkData(this);" ... >
```

Passing in `this` will let you check which form is actually being submitted:

```
function checkData(form) {
   var formName = form.id;
   //check all the data based on which form is being submitted
}
```

Comment: There are two sets of buttons. One set is just the load button, which is also the lethal one. I'll try setting that to just be a button, but when I did that before, I still had no way of telling if the user hit enter or simply wanted to load a different form, as with at least FF 3.5, not submit button value is passed. So I'm still stuck on what to do if there is post data but no submit value that tells the form whether to save or not (and thus whether to possible overwrite a saved form intentionally or unintentionally)

Comment: Do you happen to know if most browsers pass ALL form data (that has a legit value) back to the server if both forms have the same action? I'm guessing no...

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 spec specifies [synthetic click activation steps](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/editing.html#running-synthetic-click-activation-steps) for [implicit form submission](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#implicit-submission):

> A form element’s default button is the first Submit Button in tree order whose form owner is that form element.
>
> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text field is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a form whose default button has a defined activation behavior must cause the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on that default button.