# Does the HTML standard say anything about pressing Enter as submitting a form?

Tags: html, forms, browser

Every browser seems to treat pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> as submitting a form. Is this behavior specified by HTML standards, or is it just commonly implemented by browsers?

Related though goes into much more detail about the exact behavior of buttons: [Do all browser's treat enter (key 13) the same inside form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1393544/do-all-browsers-treat-enter-key-13-the-same-inside-form)

The closest I've found, from https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#implicit-submission:

> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text field is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a form whose default button has a defined activation behavior must cause the user agent to run synthetic click activation steps on that default button.

This suggests that it's platform-dependent.

Comment: Did you try to find it in the HTML5 spec?

Comment: I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: Ok fair enough!

Comment: I will add that I'm not an expert in searching documentation though I did give it a try

Comment: No that's totally fine, I think its a good habit to go to authoritive sources first, so it's good that you did =)

Answer (score 0):

In the html standard

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission

you'll find this:

> 4.10.21.2 Implicit submission
>
> A form element's default button is the first submit button in tree
> order whose form owner is that form element.
>
> If the user agent supports letting the user submit a form implicitly
> (for example, on some platforms hitting the "enter" key while a text
> control is focused implicitly submits the form), then doing so for a
> form, whose default button has activation behavior and is not
> disabled, must cause the user agent to fire a click event at that
> default button.

Essentially: the first submittable button (belonging to the form) in the DOM tree will be triggered on "Enter".