# Is it possible to set an HTML button as default inside a form?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, html

I'm working on a asp.net page and I have several buttons in my page, some of them are asp.net buttons, other are HTML `input[type=button]` elements. HTML buttons are used to make AJAX calls.

When the user press ENTER I need to set as default button one of these HTML buttons, but at the moment the first button in the page is trigged.

Is there a way to set a plain HTML button as default on my form?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1963245/multiple-submit-buttons-specifying-default-button

Comment: Move it to the "first" position?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this :

```
   // JavaScript Code
   var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    body.onkeydown = function (e) {
        if (e.keyCode === 13) {  //enter key code
         // call your html button onclick code here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm using JQuery, so I modified the code in the **Mohit Pandey** answer:

```
$("body").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // my function
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

read this article
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35180/How-To-set-Default-Button-for-ENTER-key-pressed-ev

you can use it in somewhat this way

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" defaultbutton="Button1" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you not put the form inside a panel and use the defaultbutton property

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" DefaultButton="btnSomething"> 
...
</asp:Panel>
```

Comment: If you give the button an `ID="btnSomething"` and `runat="server"`, it should.