# Multifunction/Nested Forms?

Tags: html, ruby, forms, sinatra

Is it possible to create multifunction/nested forms with sinatra?

Right now I am doing something like this:

```
<form action="/section/<%= section.id %>" method="post">

  <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put">
  <input name="heading" value="<%= section.heading>">
  <input type="submit" name="update" value="Update Section">

  <form action="/section/<%= section.id %>" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Section">
  </form>

</form>
```

With the second `<form>` section both submit buttons point to `delete /section/:id`. Without the second `<form>` both submit buttons point to `put /section/:id`.

I would like to have a single form with a button for Updateing and Deleting, but it seems that the any submit button has the value of whatever the last html verb used. Is this even possible  to do with sinatra? or am I stuck using `<a>` links instead of buttons?

Comment: Sinatra cannot work magic, HTML standards don't allow nested forms: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/379610/can-you-nest-html-forms. Duplicate then?

Comment: So, Thats why my form code doesn't work. But I already know that it doesn't work, now I know why. But I still don't know if there is a way to have a form with multiple submit buttons/actions.

Comment: Yes, you can have multiple submit buttons. The name of the input should go into the params as key, isn't this the case?

Comment: haha I don't know! thats why I'm asking... So... it sounds like what I am looking for is maybe a conditional route? ie. if 'update' is clicked then do `put /section/:id` else if 'delete' is clicked then do `delete /section/:id`. But Sinatra needs the HTML verb passed in as that hidden field, I don't see how just getting the prams of the value of the particular submit button would give me that condition.

Comment: Perhaps have two routes like `post "/section/update/:id" do...` and `post "/section/delete/:id" do...` ? Puts and delete aren't properly supported across browsers anyway. You still can't nest the forms though, you'll need to either use javascript or redesign the form, or perhaps have a conditional inside a route based on the submit button pressed (the value is passed as the key as @tokland mentions).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple submit buttons in an HTML form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48/multiple-submit-buttons-in-an-html-form)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know this now not valid syntax, javascript is required for this kind of magic.