# Spring MVC, make a button, upon click, return a string value

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am still relatively new to springMVC, I currently have some code, that will take an input from a `<form:input>` on a jsp page, and create different lists depending on the input(providing I enter the correct String). I would like to transition this into a button instead, so I could have four buttons that will return a different String, for example "one", "two", "three" and "four". That way there is no typing needed from the user.

I see that there is a `<form:button>` available but I do not know how I could return the String value from this. Also I have looked into angularJS and seen that you can call a function onClick. But again, I don't know what the implementation would have to be to tie it into my Controller. I am just not really sure how I can implement this. Any help would be appreciated.

**This is what I have being implemented at the moment :**

```
<form:form commandName="input">
<label>Enter Value</label>
<form:input path="listType" class="inputbox" />
<br>
<input type="submit" class="button" value="Enter" />
</form:form>
```

**This takes the input and stores it in an object :**

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("input")
public class EventController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/event", method= RequestMethod.GET)
public String displayEvent (Model model) {
    AccessInput userInput = new AccessInput();
    model.addAttribute("input", userInput);
    System.out.println("finished get method");
    return "event";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/event", method= RequestMethod.POST)

public String processEvent(@ModelAttribute("input")AccessInput userInput) {
    System.out.println(userInput.getListType());          //just so I know what value it has 
    return "redirect:results.html";
}
```

**This is the controller that creates my list based on the string that I pass through to the object**

```
@RestController
@SessionAttributes("input")
public class ReportController {

@RequestMapping(value="/events")
public List<Appliance> getEvents(@ModelAttribute("input")AccessInput userInput) {
    List<Appliance> events = new ArrayList<>();
    events = ProcessChoice.ofList(userInput.getListType());
    System.out.println(userInput.getListType());
    return events;
}
```

}

**Edit:**
Just to note I have resolved this, I followed the example given by Vipin Dubey, I had to change my controller. I removed the POST method and added in a `@RequestParam` as a parameter, and redirected the buttons on the `event.jsp` to `"results.html?input=one"` then took this value and added it to my model to store it in the session.

```
@Controller
@SessionAttributes("URLparam")
public class ResultController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/results.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String buttonSelect(Model model, @RequestParam("input")String input) {
    model.addAttribute("URLparam", input);
    System.out.println(input);
    return "result";
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not pick the string up as a GET param? i.e. `/events?input=one` or two or three etc. And link the buttons to go to the correct mapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two options : 
1. Short and recommended way :
Use a link and style it as a button and you can directly call your controller

```
 <a class="btn" href="/events?input=one">One</a>
 <a class="btn" href="/events?input=two">two</a>
 <a class="btn" href="/events?input=three">three</a>
 <a class="btn" href="/events?input=four">four</a>
```

2. Use jQuery or JavaScript to submit the form based on clicked button using a hidden input field in your form

```
    <!-- Buttons with classes -->
    <div id="target">
      <button class="one">One</button>
      <button class="two">two</button>
      <button class="three">three</button>
      <button class="four">four</button>
    </div>


     <!-- Your form -->
     <form:form commandName="input" id="myForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="inputbox" id="inputbox" value=""/>
     </form:form>

     // You will have to do this for each of the button which is not a recommended way
     $( ".one" ).click(function() {
     $('input[name="inputbox"]').val("one");
     //var a = $('input[name="inputbox"]').val();
     //alert(a);
     $( "#myForm" ).submit();
     });
```

Comment: could you add in any changes I would have to make to my controller? I have not seen/dealt with this before.

Comment: You don't require any changes in your controller just put the same link you get in your GET call to the four links inside href tag, only change the values i.e one/two/three/four or whatever you need in your controller. Like href="/events?input=one"

Comment: I get a 404 Error, resource not found. Do I not need to change something somewhere, to deal with the new input parameters coming from the URL?